# Simple XML not working on client server

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I built a site using simpleXML to pull content from XML pages.

I just switched the site to the client server and the pages that pull from the XML sheet don't work anymore.

Testing server was PHP version 5.2.9

Client server is PHP version 5.2.5

`allow_url_fopen` is on for both servers.

Any ideas?

```
class award{
    var $xml;
    var $awards;

    function titles(){

        $this->fullArticle();
        $xml=simplexml_load_file("awards.xml");

        foreach($xml->award as $currentAward){
            $titles=$currentAward->title;
            echo '<li><a href="'; 
            base_url();
            echo 'about/awards.php?award=';
            echo $titles; 

            echo '">' . str_replace(array('<h1>','</h1>'), '', $currentAward->$titles->h1->asXML()) . '</a></li>';
            }

    }

    function fullArticle(){

        $awards=array();
        $xml=simplexml_load_file("awards.xml");

        foreach($xml->award as $currentAward){
            array_push($awards, $currentAward->title);
        }

        return($awards);

    }


    function articleBlock($awardy){


        $xml=simplexml_load_file("awards.xml");

        foreach($xml->award as $currentAward){
            if($currentAward->title = $awardy ){ 
                echo str_replace(array('<'.$awardy.'>','</'.$awardy.'>'), '', $currentAward->$awardy->asXML());
            } 

            }


    }
}
```

Comment: Code                   ?

Comment: im thinking it has to do with php.ini ?

Comment: 1. Describe What you expect to happen;

2. Describe what's actually happening (behavior differences, errors, etc.);

3. Show your code;

4. Show any data sources (XML files, etc);

Comment: im sorry I will try a bit longer to fix myself too long to explain for now.

Comment: has nothing to do with your problem, but "var" is deprecated, use "public" instead

Comment: thanks for the tip. I found my problem. The testing server i was using had php_value register_globals=1 and so I didnt use $_GET in my code. The client server has php_value register_globals=1 so it needs $_GET

Comment: The client server has php_value register_globals=0

Answer (score 1):

Add more error handling and debug code

```
<?php
assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, 1);
assert_options(ASSERT_BAIL, 1);
assert_options(ASSERT_QUIET_EVAL, 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class award {
    function titles() {
        $xml=simplexml_load_file("awards.xml");
        if (!$xml) {
            throw new Exception("cannot read awards.xml");
        }

        assert( isset($xml->award) );

        foreach($xml->award as $currentAward) {
            assert( isset($currentAward->title) );
            assert( isset($currentAward->$titles) );
            assert( isset($currentAward->$titles->h1) );

            $titles=(string)$currentAward->title;
            echo '<li><a href="';
            base_url();
            echo 'about/awards.php?award=';
            echo urlencode($titles);

            echo '">' . str_replace(array('<h1>','</h1>'), '', $currentAward->$titles->h1->asXML()) . '</a></li>';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if your IP address permission is enabled on your server. If not then enable it.